# How to switch between text input and h4 element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to switch between a h4 element and a text input element when I double click on the h4 element .

When I finished I click on Enter , the input switch to h4.

I use it in VueJs with a loop to display all the comments

for now I have this :

```
<h4 @dblclick="editComment(text)">{{text}}</h4>
```

```
editComment(item){
    item = 'New Comment'
    };
```

Comment: add a toggle/boolean, then use `v-if` and `v-else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

define a variable toggle and initially define it as true and then use v-if on your elements.

```
<input @dblclick="toggle=!toggle" v-if="toggle" /> 

<h4 v-if="!toggle" @dblclick="editComment(text)">{{text}}</h4>

editComment(item){
    item = 'New Comment';
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    };
```